# Show that any positive proper fraction can be expressed as the sum of reciprocals of distinct positive integers.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

First, write the fraction as $\frac{a}{ax-r}$. For $r=0$, the problem is trivial. For $r>0$, $\frac{a}{ax-r} = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{r}{x(ax-r)}$. I tried several algebraic manipulations to prove the above expression for $r+1$ using weak induction with little success, so I believe the proof requires the use of strong induction. However, I have never used strong induction and am not familiar with it at all.

Comment: Try to show $\frac{a}{ax-r} = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{r}{\color{red}{x}(ax-r)}$ instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical thing to note is that $r \lt a$ as it is the number you need to add to the denominator to get a multiple of $a$.  Now you have a new fraction $\frac r{x(ax-r)}$ and you can do the same thing.  Write it as $\frac r{br-c}$.  If $c=0$ you are done.  If not, $\frac r{br-c}=\frac 1b=\frac c{br-c}$ with $c \lt r$.  Now the fact that there are no infinite descending sequences of naturals means you will eventually terminate.